# Which file handles the redirection code in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a question & answer site in **Laravel**, when user log-in to the site and then if he goes to **URL** and then type `localhost/my-site/login`, *I mean* **tries to open the login page again after login**, then it redirects to `localhost/my-site/home` by default but I need to redirect it to `localhost/my-site/`, I need to know that which file contains this code, I have changed this `protected $redirectTo = '/';` in **LoginController** but not working.

Comment: (Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers)

that trait is handling the login functionality

Comment: Bro checked there not found, also checked here `use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;` both of these not found in these also.

Comment: did you use (make:auth) command ?

Comment: Yes I used that.

Comment: which version you use ?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.7

Comment: Bro I found that, thanks

Comment: answer the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185687/discussion-between-ahmad-elkenany-and-usman-developer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it here RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware.

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

I just replaced `return redirect('/home');` with `return redirect('/');`

Comment: It's correct you can modify the redirection in middleware. If you are not using Redirection middleware maybe you can config `protected $redirectTo = '/main';` in your authentication controller.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not working even I changed it in the both controllers, as I have also mentioned that 

Comment: Could you explain and show us how it your login process?

Comment: @ManuelEduardoRomero it's default login setup using `php artisan make:auth` command.

Comment: If your are using default auth the login form is going to "AuthController@login". So this controller maybe is inheriting from "AuthenticatesUsers" please check this. In this case you can overwrite `protected $redirectTo = '/';` in AuthController. If it doesnt work maybe you can overwrite `protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)`. This last method run when the user was authenticated. So you can redirect there to home. Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Bro i have answered my question see that I have solved it, and thanks for commenting...

Answer (score 0):

If you have `LoginController` under `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` add this property `protected $redirectTo = '/whatever-route-you-want'`

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
```